# How to replace the generic Google TTS service?

Tags: text-to-speech

I kind of hate the voice used for navigation, alarm clock. Seems everything is using that same voice. Too robotic for my liking. I found [IVONA Text-to-Speech Voices](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ivona.tts&hl=en) | TTS Voices | Text To Voice

Not sure how good it is. Is there a better app than Ivona?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ivona voice sounds the best hands down (especially Amy and the new not yet on Android Salli voice). Works great on all apps for me. Sadly, whenever I reboot phone, Ivona no longer works. Only fix is to reinstall the whole thing which is a total PITA. I still do it though cause it sounds so much better then any of the other choices.

Answer (score 0):

If it's possible, you can update to Jelly Bean (regular or via mod).

Android 4.1 comes with a new Google TTS engine that sounds *very* natural and IMHO tops SVOX 
classic (at least the german voice as of Q3/2012).

Included languages so far are:

- English (US or UK accent)
- Spanish
- French
- Italian
- German